# What's happening with vector displacement 2.79b?

Tags: displacement, vector

pretty quick question. I use the vector displacement node in order to add greebling to models. The latest version of 2.79b doesn't have that node, which seems to be why sheepit render farm is returning "flat" non displaced models.

Does anyone know if I should just wait for an update? Or if there is a way to do displacement without the vector displacement node?

Thanks guys, appreciate any advice!

Comment: You need to download the daily build to get that feature, it is an experimental feature.

Comment: @Denis Well not so much an experimental feature, it is a new feature that was added after the 2.79 release and hasn't been included in an official release yet. It is in 2.80 alpha2 but I don't think that helps with using sheep it.

Answer (score 0):

Try connect it directly. For example, connect Image Texture color output to Displacement input of Material Output node.